# fix Camera orientation in android

Tags: android, camera

I have app that take picture. My problem is orientation of image that save on device . I solve preview orientation use many method but it isn't affect on image that save on device.
method that I use to fix problem :

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

&

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

&

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
mParameters.setRotation(90);
mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
```

&
in AndroidMainfest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and also method that describe in official site for android developer and it say :
" If you want to make the camera image show in the same orientation as the display, you can use the following code " in this address:
[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29)

all of this method work fine for camera preview orientation but not on saved image.
also I don't want to use this :

```
String path = pictureFile.getPath().toString();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

because this method use saved image and rotate it and save it again and reduce quality of image.
any idea except this methods ? thank's

Comment: You can perform lossless rotation, as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706665/lossless-jpeg-rotate-90-180-270-degrees-in-java.