# samsung galaxy s2 always treat camera view as landscape?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, camera, landscape

My app ask the user to take a photo and then saves it.

I have noticed that Samsung Galaxy S2 takes a portrait photo

but when I save it to the server I see it in landscape only in the server.

(even though it was taken in portrait).

It doesn't happen for me with other phones (Samsung S4, Nexus 5).

When I look at the photo gallery I see the photo in portrait.

**Update**

The weird thing is that in my java code it seemed to be portrait orientation

so I really don't get it:

```
            if (getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                //a             
}else {
                //b
            }
```

But i saw something odd: the settings and other native dialog are all landscape when using S2 camera. see attachment:

**Update2**

I have checked `exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION` and got 6 ( ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)

So i have tried to set this to ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 or ORIENTATION_NORMAL

but it didn't help

```
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
      exif = new ExifInterface(imageFilename);
      int orientation =
          exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
      exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
          String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270));
      exif.saveAttributes();
      orientation =
          exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
      boolean b = orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you should try it. this problem is happening with samsung devices. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245556/exif-orientation-tag-value-always-0-for-image-taken-with-portrait-camera-app-and

Comment: GovindRathod  please see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The documentation of [Camera.Parameters.setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)) is very clear:

> The camera driver may set orientation in the EXIF header without
>   rotating the picture. Or the driver may rotate the picture and the
>   EXIF thumbnail. If the Jpeg picture is rotated, the orientation in the
>   EXIF header will be missing or 1 (row #0 is top and column #0 is left
>   side).

The solution is to actually perform rotation of the pictures before upload, or maybe on the server (the choice depends on your product requirements). You can use a Java [MediaUtil](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/) library, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302674/192373.

Comment: thanks. why does setting the exif tag to be "rotation_undefined" or "rotation_noraml"? I managed to set it to the desired value, but the image is still rotated on the server.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you suggest `The solution is to actually perform rotation of the pictures before upload` and not using `public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)` ?

Comment: In which situation did you see "rotation_undefined"?

Comment: Let me explain. Even when EXIF flag defines the correct orientation, some image viewers ignore this flag and display the image rotated. You cannot fix the world, so if you want your images to be universally correct, you can perform the rotation according to EXIF flags (or to device orientation).

Comment: "rotation_undefined" when i check the tags on my Samsung Note 2

Comment: thanks. how about using Camera object instead of "action intent" and there setting "setRotation" - will this change the preview before capture screen or what actually does it do?

Comment: The way the device treats rotated capture is the same for Camera object and `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I didn't get your last sentence

Comment: what will  "setRotation" do to my jpeg or to the camera preview?

Comment: Camera.Parameters.setRotation() does not effect the preview. Its purpose is to rotate the captured Jpeg. Some devices actually rotate the image, but others only set the EXIF flag. There is a different API, Camera.setOrientation(), which takes care of preview, but not takePicture().